# Every tabs in firefox is blank

Tags: 20.04, firefox, certificates, citrix

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I really am a beginner on Linux.

The problem: Every tabs opened on firefox are blank

When: Every time : the welcoming page is blank and when i try to open a bookmark, type an URL, open in another tab, in private mode (it's just a purple page) i only have blank tabs. Extensions pop-ups are empty and the configuration pages from the burger menu do not open. The only not-blank tab i can open is the troubleshooting information's page

What I tried: I obviously tried to restart my computer, to check my internet connection. I did refresh firefox, restart with add-ons disabled and clear startup cache. I changed my mozilla profile to a new. I tried to uninstall/reinstall firefox this way:

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
sudo rm -Rf /etc/firefox/
sudo rm -Rf /usr/lib/firefox*
```

It didn't work, so I tried this other way to uninstall but it didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support

E: Impossible de trouver le paquet firefox-globalmenu
E: Impossible de trouver le paquet firefox-gnome-support
```

My conclusion is then that the firefox's files are not the problem but that firefox may use a third party file corrupted

Before this happened I followed a guide to install Citrix and ICAClient to use a distant computer, and used these commands

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
sudo c_rehash /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/
```

So it might come from the ca-certificates files having been altered ?
My question then is where do you think it might come from and what can I do, where should I look at ?

Thank you so much for reading this to the end and even more if you take time to answer.

Comment: You should [report a problem](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1091634) to mozilla.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem today, Firefox works perfectly then I installed Citrix Workspace via .deb file, tried to connect with ica file on Citrix and blank pages on FF.

Nothing with uninstall, install other version, new profile, just like you.

**What works for me :**

I removed Citrix:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove -y icaclient
```

Then I downloaded tar.gz instead of .deb file, followed instructions on :

[Citrix Documentation Website](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux/install.html)

Section : "Install using a tarball package"

It work fine now for me.

Hope it helps

Comment: I had the exact same problem with Firefox on Ubuntu 21.04. Always the message `[Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost`. I tested to downgrade firefox, try Nightly, installing/removing lots of packages, opening it on a new user... nothing to do. But your solution worked perfectly ! I just un-installed the icaclient_21.4.0.11_amd64.deb. You just saved my day.

Comment: The problem is also related here : https://askubuntu.com/a/1327931/558294 . For my part, I was able to use citrix after reinstallation of the critix workspace without selecting the protection application components. Also work in a virtual machine.

Comment: I've tried this answer 1st and it works! If I'd seen @jomuller's comment I'd have tried that first. Looks like it's a Citrix problem not Firefox.